# What is the best practice in using notification bar for media player app in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, media-player

I have 2 activities (SongListActivity and PlayerActivity). While a song is playing, my app would show on notification bar.

Currently, the notification references to PlayerActivity. And here are my cases when notification is clicked:

1. App is on foreground: PlayerActivity appears, and when user clicks back, it backs to the SongListActivity (ok).
2. App is on background: PlayerActivity appears, and when user clicks back, SongListActivity does not appear (my problem).

What is the best practice to solve case 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the case where [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) can be used to create a synthetic back stack (i.e., a whole set of activities even if none already exist). The training for [Preserving Navigation when starting an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html) goes through its usage.

Note that it assumes you've set up your activities for proper [Up navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) between your activities such as the following:

```
<activity
  android:name=".PlayerActivity"
  android:parentActivityName=".SongListActivity ">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".SongListActivity "/>
</activity>
```